# nodejs - check if image is blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, screenshot

I'm creating a testing app that spits out an image for url entered by user.
screenshots are taken with phantomjs + nightmarejs.

Sometimes user enters nonexistent url so image screenshot is blank. 
Is there any lib in nodejs that allows me to check if image is blank? or maybe a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Sometimes user enters nonexistent url so image screenshot is blank. Is
>   there any lib in nodejs that allows me to check if image is blank? or
>   maybe a better approach?

Yes, there is a better approach. Check if URL gives you 404 error before taking screenshot and return error to user if it does.

Comment: You would avoid a lot of unnecessary work with taking screenshot. You just need to fire 1 request and check if it fails. It's few lines of code. Try to get same effect with image library, we'll see what's more complicated, time-consuming, CPU intensive, but I think I already know.